# __LP64__ check when compiling Python.framework on OSX?

Tags: python, macos, compilation

I'm building Python from source on MacOSX against the 10.6 SDK. I'm using --with-universal-archs="intel" and --enable-framework which should create a framework compatible with both 32bit and 64bit architectures. However, I checked the Apple provided Framework against the compiled one and I have some differences. This one in particular is breaking one of packages I'm trying to install:

pyconfig.h in my compiled framework shows:

```
/* The size of `uintptr_t', as computed by sizeof. */
#define SIZEOF_UINTPTR_T 8
```

What it should show is the following:

```
/* The size of `uintptr_t', as computed by sizeof. */
#ifdef __LP64__
#define SIZEOF_UINTPTR_T 8
#else
#define SIZEOF_UINTPTR_T 4
#endif
```

Any ideas on how to recreate the Apple supplied Python.framework?